# How to break the build into several files?

Tags: requirejs, rjs

In case of a very lengthy built file, I would like to be able to break it into several parts. For instance, the vendors could be all minified into a `vendor.built.js` file and the rest into an `app.built.js` file.

How this can be done?

Comment: If the vendor files are just plain JS, then do they provide a minified version? If so, just concatenate those and use r.js separately for your modules.

Comment: I need to require these libraries inside modules, so if somehow i had r.js ignore these during the build how does require know that they have been loaded ?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting down voted, if i am missing something please share some insights.

Answer (score 1):

I have a proposed solution for this in my [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy) project.

It accomplishes something a *little different than what you ask* though: It splits the application into lazy-loaded modules, as easy (from the developer's perspective) as writing (note the usage of the `lazy!` plugin):

```
define(["eager-module", "lazy!lazy-module"], function(eager, lazy) {...})
```

And then using it with through a promise:

```
lazy.get().then(function(real_module) {...});
```

The `lazy-module` will be loaded once, the first time `.get()` is called.

For the example above, the build process would produce 2 js files: On containing the main module, the `eager-module` and all their dependencies. And one containing the `lazy-module` and all its dependencies that were not included in the previous file/bundle.

The require-lazy project has a few examples that are very simple to setup, you only require Node.js.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, I do have a trick to "lazy load" module and I think it similar to what your script does. The problem is that it doesn't work for shimming.

Comment: I don't know how you are doing it, but requir-lazy works with shimming, look at the [example](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy/tree/master/examples/shim).

Comment: Close enough, thanks again Nikos, I up your answer but can't accept it as final answer for now as i feel there should be a native solution or at least something with less overhead. (I think you'll get the bounty rep anyway)